# How do I prevent double submit of linkbutton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

How can I prevent double submit of link button. I have a payment button, I want to disable it as soon as somebody clicks on it and re-enable it if the payment fails. I am using AJAX and programmatic post to payment gateway.

I can disable the linkbutton using this code:

```
asp:LinkButton ID="btnPayment"  runat="server" onClientClick="this.disabled=true;__doPostBack(this.id,'');" Text='<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Author")%>' ></asp:LinkButton>
```

But how do I enable it back when payment fails?

Comment: Do you call some service with $.ajax() and unblock link by result? Do You want only enabled button or make click with javascript too? Do you need any poastback after click? If you need postback then in  which moment? Can solution use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I think in the button click handler if the payment failed you can write the code to execute javascript like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(this.Page, typeof(Page) , "enableBtn" , "$('[$=btnPayment].removeAttr(disabled)')" , true);
```

This requires jquery.

ALternatively you can call document,getelementbyID also if you dont want to use jquery.

Let me know if this is not what you want

I have a one more solution but that seems to be nasty:

In the beginning

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnPayment"  runat="server" Text='<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Author")%>' ></asp:LinkButton>
```

And using jquery do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  $('id$=btnPayment').live("click", function(e) {

  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");  
  __doPostBack($(this).attr("id"),'');
   e.preventDefault();
 });  });
```

So with Ajax you removed the disabled attribute so the link button becomes clickable again.

Will this make sense

Comment: Thanks but removing disabled alone shouldn't work. I have also used __doPostBack(this.id,''); to prevent postback.

Comment: I had added one more solution but i am not sure whether this is what you want or not

Answer (score 0):

In code behind, You can enable and disable code.
On click, first disable link button and enable it if payment succeed.
because above code will also do server trip, ajax call is not firing.

```
btnLogin.Enabled = false;
if (txtUserName.Text == "hh") btnLogin.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: This is not at all an answer. You are writing it in code behind. What if user presses submit button 2 times before this code is executed?

Comment: How about capturing the double click event?

Comment: then use bind or unbind method.. $(button).unbind('click');